# How to overload << operator without friend function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to overload << operator to print Currency (user defined type)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Currency
{
  int Dollar;
  int Cents;

  ostream& operator<< (ostream &out)
  {
    out << "(" << Dollar << ", " << Cents << ")";
    return out;
  }
};



template<typename T>
void DisplayValue(T tValue)  
{
   cout << tValue << endl;
}

int main() {

Currency c;
c.Dollar = 10;
c.Cents = 54;

DisplayValue(20); // <int>
DisplayValue("This is text"); // <const char*>
DisplayValue(20.4 * 3.14); // <double>
DisplayValue(c); // Works. compiler will be happy now. 
return 0;
}
```

But getting the following error.

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void DisplayValue(T) [with T = Currency]’:
prog.cpp:34:16:   required from here
prog.cpp:22:9: error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
    cout << tValue << endl;
         ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39:0,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:602:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = Currency]’
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
     ^
```

Can anyone help me if i am missing any thing or doing anything wrong here?

Comment: your overload function is not correct

Comment: Can you please guide me what is wrong. I am not able to figure out. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to fix the operator by adding `Currency const& c` as the second parameter (as it come s on the right hand side).

Then you have two options:

#### 1: Add Friend

```
struct Currency
{
  int Dollar;
  int Cents;

  friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Currency const& c)
  {
    return out << "(" << c.Dollar << ", " << c.Cents << ")";
  }
};
```

#### 2: Move the definition outside the class

```
struct Currency
{
  int Dollar;
  int Cents;
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Currency const& c)
{
  return out << "(" << C.Dollar << ", " << c.Cents << ")";
}
```

Either works and is fine.
Personally I like option-1 as it documents the tight coupling of the output operator to the class that it is outputting. But this is such a simple case that either works just fine.

The reason that it can not be a member is that the first parameter is a stream (the left hand side value of the operator is the first parameter). This does not work for members as the first parameter is the hidden this parameter. So technically you could add this method to `std::ostream`. Unfortunately you don't have accesses (and not allowed to) modify `std::ostream`. As a result you must make it a free standing function.

#### Example showing it can be a member:

```
struct X
{
    std::ostream operator<<(int y)
    {
        return std::cout << y << " -- An int\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    X   x;
    x << 5;
}
```

That works fine here.
This is because the compiler translates

```
x << 5;
```

into

```
// not real code (pseudo thought experiment code).
operator<<(x, 5)
      // Equivalent to:
                X::operator<<(int y)
      // or
                operator<<(X& x, int y)
```

Because x has a member function `operator<<` this works fine. If `x` did not have a member function called `operator<<` then the compiler would look for a free standing function that takes two parameters with `X` as the first and `int` as the second.

Answer (score 8):

You don't put it into your class, you put if afterwards. Since your members are `public` there is no need to declare it a `friend`:

```
struct Currency
{
    int Dollar;
    int Cents;
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const Currency& c)
{
    out << "(" << c.Dollar << ", " << c.Cents << ")";
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Keeping this outside class definition is working fine. Thanks a lot. My doubt is why we need to keep it outside class definition??

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal because keeping it inside the class will make it have implicit `this` pointer... which we don't want...

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal You don't *have* to keep it outside, but in your case there is no reason to put it inside. Only if you need to access `private` (or `protected`) member variables or methods from the class you need to declare the method a `friend` inside of the class. If it is declared a `friend`, the signature still needs to be the same as for the free method and the implementation can still remain outside of the class/struct.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal, also, most of the times a friend is not needed, you should use inline getters instead without performance penalty.

Answer (score 2):

Overload it like below, and put it outside of class declaration (you don't need friendship!):

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const Currency &c)
{                                 //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  out << "(" << c.Dollar << ", " << c.Cents << ")";
  return out;
}
```

---

Funny thing with your code is, you have to use the operator like this:

```
c << cout; // !!
```

Comment: Probably the same person that downvoted me and probably the same reason - have a guess :) (FWIW, you got my +1 some time ago for the `c<<cout`)

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written your inserter method, the only way to get it to work would be to do:

```
c << std::cout;
```

But instead, if you know your inserters won't need to access any private variables, simply do as the other answers say and create a global function that takes both arguments:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Currency& c);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what i want is, i want to write the operator overloading function inside the class. I made the changes in class like this.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal Why would you need this? What is the benefit?

Comment: Because in that case, it will be the part of class. every thing will be in single unit.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal Sorry, but it's impossible to do that. Global functions are just that, *global*. Maybe you can put both the class and the function inside one namespace...

Comment: So i just want to understand, is there any limitation with << operator. Because i am able to overload all other operators like +, +=, >= etc. inside class itself, without an issues/errors. Thanks.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal There's no limitation. Maybe you're just confused about how operator overloading works.

Comment: @0x499602D2: It has the benefit of explicitly documenting the tight coupling between the output operator and the class. A `friend` declaration is part of the public API of the class and thus is tightly bound to the class.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class myclass
{
    int x;
    public:
    myclass() //constructor
    {
        x=5;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &outStreamObject,myclass &object); //standard way

    void operator<<(ostream &outStreamObject) //Another way.
    {
        outStreamObject<<this->x;
    }


};
 ostream& operator<<(ostream &outStreamObject,myclass &object)
{
    cout<<object.x;
    return outStreamObject;
}
int main()
{
    //standard way of overload the extraction operator
    myclass object1,object2;
    cout<<object1<<" "<<object2;
    cout<<endl;
    //overloading the extraction operator with using friend function
    object1.operator<<(cout);
    return 0;
}
```

It is not at all necessary that the insertion and the extraction operators can be overloaded only by using the friend function.
The above code overloads the extraction operator with and without the friend function. The friend function implementation is favoured because cout can be used the way it is used for other datatypes.
Similary you can overload the insertion operator.

Comment: Sorry but this is such a poor example, doing a disservice particularly for beginners to the language. For example there is a lack of using initialisation lists, poor variable naming, return types for << that prevent chaining and break convention, bad code formatting and lack of WS. Good practice should be demonstrated even in examples.

Comment: @Nick some people and some websites say that it is mandatory to use a friend function when overloading the extraction or the insertion operator. I just wanted to provide a counterexample. But you are correct I didn't format the question properly. I have updated it.

Answer (score -3):

You need to make it friend :
Also you need to give it the right arguments. an ostream and the currency.

```
  friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& stream, const Currency& c )
  {
    stream << "(" << c.Dollar << ", " << c.Cents << ")";
    return stream;
  }
```

**Edit:**
As you can see in the comments, you don't have to make it friend. You can put it outside the structure.

```
Currency c;
c.Dollar = 10;
c.Cents = 54;

DisplayValue(c); // Works. compiler will be happy now.
```

Comment: Why does the OP "need to make it friend"?

Comment: @DanielFrey If it's inside his structure it has to be a friend. Otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: If it's inside the `struct`, yes, but there is no reason it has to be inside the `struct` - it does not need to access anything `private` (or `protected`) from the `struct`.

Comment: @DanielFrey It does what he asked for, doesn't it? And it is not even bad.

Comment: @NormalPeopleScareMe It does work (the *first* `operator<<` in the answer), but the wording was too strong for my taste which is why I left a comment (For the record: I didn't downvote). That **second** overload for "cents" OTOH will not work, it should be removed.

Comment: @DanielFrey The second part seems to work... I just don't get the braces.

Comment: @NormalPeopleScareMe Which means it *doesn't* work. It's taking the normal `operator<<` for `int`.

Comment: Putting it inside and marking it friend is fine. Declaring it a friend is actual good practice as you are documenting in the code the tight coupling of the `operator<<` to the structure. Also by keeping it close (inside is very close) to the class you make it easy to see that it work with the class. There is no downside here.